# Updating rootScope variable upon state navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, state

I have a number of UI-Router states and in the controller of each router, I attach a context object to the rootScope that specify what is hidden or shown on a global navbar when that state is active.

```
$rootScope.context = { showSearch: true, hideBack: true }; // defaults
```

And for each controller I have the following

```
function updateContext() {
    $rootScope.context = undefined;
    $rootScope = { showSearch: true, hideBack: true };
}
```

And In the nave template I have the following

```
<nav>
    <nav-search ng-show="context.showSearch"></nav-search>
    <nav-back ng-hide="context.hideBack"></nav-back>
</nav>
```

This works alright, but the problem is that when a person navigates to a `state A` and then to `state B`, when the user goes back to state A, the controller is not "executed" again and so the context doesn't get updated to A's context

I'd like to know how to work around this. Also if it's possible to add such information in the UI-Router state definitions so I can access in the template, that would be fine too.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The way to go, *I'd suggest,* is to properly use `controller`/`$scope` life-cycle. While during creation we set values, during destruction we can cleanup, or reset previous. So, to show it in code, we could/should do:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
   // keep what was set
   var oldValues = { 
       showSearch: $rootScope.showSearch || true, 
       hideBack:   $rootScope.hideBack || true, 
   };
   ...
   // do some magic
   ...
   // reset on state / view leave
   $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
      $rootScope.showSearch = oldValues.showSearch;
      $rootScope.hideBack   = oldValues.hideBack ;
   });
}])
```

> BTW: Working with `$rootScope` is like working with any other Singleton. So, maybe - move that all from *$rootScope* into some custom `StateHolder` factory/service.